# intelliJ IDEA | xml validation error

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0 ../wcsAll.xsd"
    service="WCS" version="2.0.0">
    <wcs:CoverageId>C0001</wcs:CoverageId>
</wcs:GetCoverage>
```

I am trying to validate this `XML` file using `IntelliJ IDEA` however I get an error -

```
External resource http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 is not registered
Premature end of file.
```

I recently switched to `IntelliJ`, so the same piece of `XML` validates fine on `NetBeans`, the schema `../wcsAll.xsd` is at the proper location.

Searching around, I found a suggestion to put `"http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"` in the list of ignore external resources; but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else with this problem, you have to delete workspace.xml in the .idea hidden folder!

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try not to set it as ignored but to set absolute path to this resource?

Which version of IntelliJ IDEA you are using ?
As i know latest version helps you resolve this issue automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when the Android Studio unexpectedly closed.

I solved this error by removing the file *PROJECT_ROOT*.idea/workspace.xml

Answer (score 1):

In the version of IntelliJ IDEA I'm using, if I use '/../wcsAll.xsd' then I can validate against an xsd in the parent directory of the xml file.  Very confusing, because every other XML editor I've used needs that relative path to be '../wcsAll.xsd'